# Save same object into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a function that adds a ledger to my db. The record is saved into an array each time it satisfies the criteria. The else block saves properly but the if block saves only the second part. How do I save both ledgers in my if block into the array?

```
 //function that pushes the ledger
 .......
 for (let i = 0; i < myledger.length; i++) {
     if (myledger[i].type === 'test' || myledger[i].type === 'Security' 
        || myledger[i].type === 'Books'){

            myledger.push(i)
    }



 if(status === active){
      record {
         type: "Books",
         Fee: 3000
      },
      record {
         type: "Security",
         Fee: 1000
      },
   }
   else {
      record {
         type: "test",
         Fee: 10000
      }
   }
```

Comment: The code, as shown, should be throwing a syntax error.

Comment: Yeah it's not the exact code. Just trying to pass the idea of what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: @Hopez it's ambiguous to us for the same reason it's ambiguous to the parser. Please post real (syntactically valid) code. Even if it doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. As you can see by the answers you've received, if you post invalid code, people will focus on that, not on what you are trying to do. Also, it's not clear what the code in the bottom half of your code block has to do with the code in the top half. Please help us understand that.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @MikeMcCaughan

Answer (score 0):

The problem is only with your multi-object assignment. You were trying to add two object at once but due to statement error, the second one is overlapping the first one.

Try with a simple array method.

```
records = [
    {
        type: "Books",
        Fee: 3000
    },
    {
        type: "Security",
        Fee: 1000
    }
];
```

Comment: Can you accept the answer and vote it up if it helped?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the issue lies here:

```
  record {
     type: "Books",
     Fee: 3000
  },
  record {
     type: "Security",
     Fee: 1000
  },
```

I take it you're trying to add each of these records to a 'records' array, but have made a syntactical error. What you're doing now looks more akin to defining an object property 'record' - because you define it twice, the second record property is overwriting the first.

Instead, you'd probably want to do something like this:

```
records.push(
    {
        type: "Books",
        Fee: 3000
    },
    {
        type: "Security",
        Fee: 1000
    }
);
```

Of course, the exact implementation depends on what you're trying to do. Hope this helps.